# web.xml session timeout is not respected by Google Chrome?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7, java-ee-6, web.xml

My web app's web.xml defines session timeout as follows.

```
<session-config>
     <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

But when I check saved session cookie in chrome, it says

```
Expires:  When the browsing session ends
```

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the cookie which will timeout. It's the session stored on the application server. When you make a request after the timeout period has elapsed Tomcat will realise that the session has expired and take appropriate action.

If you start a new session you will get a new sessionId in your JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought it's the same timeout value there are in both server side session and JSESSIONID cookie. Apparently, it's not correct. It's fine. What I want to know is the expire time of a particular session. Is there a way I can see that? Where in Application Server these sessions are stored? Thanks.

Comment: "What I want to know is the expire time of a particular session". This is what you've configured in your web.xml. The storage of these sessions will vary from application server to application server.

Comment: Aren't there any session monitoring tools available?